# express.js - redirect to another URL through middleware if condition doesn't match

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I have an admin portal and I implemented another configuration functionality for admin within the portal. I need to keep **/admin/configure** out of authentication but others should be.

I am talking about following url -

**/admin/***
and
**/admin/configure**

I am trying to create a `middleware` which enables me to redirect to login page when url is **/admin/*** not **/admin/configure**

I am trying with following code -

```
app.use('/admin/*', (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.path == '/admin/configure'){
        next();
    }

    if(req.session.user_id){
        next();
    } else{
        res.redirect('/admin/login');
    }
});
```

But it moves back with an error -

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Can you please figure out the issue with a best practice way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting to `/admin/login` which executes the same `/admin/*` route logic, causing infinite redirects.
Either do the same individual check for `/admin/login` as you do for `/admin/configure`, or change its route.